# Exponential map smooth

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to prove the smoothness of exponential map for complex matrix as a map from $C^n\to C^n$. In particular, given $A\in M_n(C)$ we have $e^A=\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}A^n$. The easiest solution I've read says:

> $A^n$ has component which are $n$-homogenous polynomial in the components of A. Therefore, $e^A$ has component which are convergent power series (in the component of A) in $M_n(C)$.

For me, it is not clear how to find that power series for the components. For example, if $A=(a_{ij})$, then the $ij$-component of $A^n$ is  $\sum_{k_1, \dots, k_{n-1}=1} a_{i,k_1} a_{k_1,k_2}... a_{k_{n-1},j}$ (the $n$-homogenous polynomial).  When I fix the components of A (except one, say x) I can't write $\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n!}A^n=\sum_{n=0}^m a_nx^n$ for some fixed scalar $a_n$ because $a_n$ would change for every $m$.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2129365/81360) to be helpful

Comment: You can read a proof in Example 3.35 of the book F. Warner "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups" (Springer, 1983). He works out some inequalities for the matrix coefficients in the series from which he gets uniform (on compacts) absolute convergence. From there, differentiability follows.